# Can I use Reactive Extensions in a MonoTouch project?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, system.reactive, xamarin

There is a port of Rx called [mono-reactive](https://github.com/atsushieno/mono-reactive) that contains a MonoTouch project but the author [announced ten days ago](https://github.com/atsushieno/mono-reactive/commit/a030a7e2792eb239e1d5afa8645880264f692ff9) he is abandoning the project in favor of Microsoft open source implementation:

> I happily announce that I'm not going to work on this code base anymore
>   now that Microsoft has open-sourced Reactive Extensions in Apache license.
>   http://rx.codeplex.com/

MonoDevelop hangs trying to open Rx.sln in [Rx master](http://rx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ef6a42709f49) and there isn't a MonoTouch target there anyway. [PCL support is not there yet for MonoTouch too](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Application_Fundamentals/Building_Cross_Platform_Applications/Part_3_-_Setting_Up_A_Xamarin_Cross_Platform_Solution).

I'm wondering if anyone already put up a MonoTouch-compatible project for Rx and whether it is actually usable in production.

Comment: You might try downloading the source and creating a MonoTouch library project with all the Rx files linked in. (this might be the only way to do it right now)

Comment: You might want to read this http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/288785/how-to-use-reactive-extensions-on-ios-.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Microsoft Rx

I put up a project myself, combining **Core**, **Interfaces**, **Linq** and **PlatformServices** from [Rx's codeplex](https://rx.codeplex.com).
There you go:

**https://github.com/stampsy/rx-monotouch**

It works fine with reference types, much less so with value types (see below).
<s>Unfortunately it doesn't compile due to bug <s>[8329](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8329)</s> and [9087](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=9087).</s> It compiles just fine now.

#### mono-reactive

I also used [mono-reactive](https://github.com/atsushieno/mono-reactive) and it worked pretty well for me. While Microsoft's implementation seems more concise and reliable, mono-reactive is smaller and easier to fix when really needed.

You can try both and see what works best for you.
Happy observing!

#### Mitigating Crashes

With both frameworks I often ran into crashes caused by AOT
limitations on the device. I was told by Rolf of Xamarin that you can
often work around most AOT limitations by **not using value types** as
Rx generic type parameters.

For example, `IObservable<bool>` extensions will probably crash on the device, and so will `IObservable<long>`, but reference types should work fine with most methods.

In [my version of Rx](https://github.com/stampsy/rx-monotouch) I added `IntervalSafe` method that returns `Unit` (which I changed to be a reference type, rather than a struct) instead of `long`, and thus doesn't cause tens of crashes all over the codebase.

Some Rx methods still crash, but **it's fairly easy to fix these crashes**.

See [`Throttle` fix](https://github.com/stampsy/rx-monotouch/commit/e34e12dcf44a71d357cc419c15ff8ee8b79b819c) by Costo or [my `Buffer` fix](https://github.com/stampsy/rx-monotouch/commit/032faef6a97c4804016d9caf7cdcda3571fe3251) for reference.
I will happily merge pull requests that address other Rx methods and their overloads.

Comment: It is still actual w.r.t. Reactive Extensions (2.2.5) released by Microsoft?

Comment: @SargeBorsch Probably not, but worth checking. MonoTouch has seen some improvements wrt AOT generic support, but it's best if you see for yourself, because I haven't played with it for a couple of years.

Comment: OK, thank you. We probably will try soon… By the way, I can even add the Rx-Main package to a PCL project.